# Linux SOL: console=tty0 console=ttyS0: what if the ttyS0 is disabled physically or disconnected?

Tags: linux, kernel, console

When I use SOL(serial-over-lan), I specified kernel options such as:

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS0
```

But different machine has different configuration of SOL, some only enable ttyS0, some only enable ttyS1.

From the Linux documentation https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel.html,

> Kernel messages will appear on both the first virtual terminal and the serial port. Messages from the init system and the system logger will appear only on the first serial port. This can be slightly confusing when looking at the attached monitor: the machine will appear to boot and then hang. Don't panic, the init system has started but is now printing messages to the serial port but is printing nothing to the screen. If a getty has been configured then a login: prompt will eventually appear on the attached monitor.

so I am curious that

- what will happen if the tty**S**? is physically disabled?
- what will happen if the tty**S**? is not connected by a client actually?

From my experience, it seem works well in above cases, I can see message from the tty0 (BMC remote console) even if I specified wrong tty**S**? (i.e, disabled).

But I can not find documentation about above cases, so maybe some kernel developers know this.